# Keep rows of dataframe if multiple conditions met

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, sample

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["EQ", "CB", "CB", "FF", "EQ", "EQ", "CB", "CB"],
                   'B': ["ANT", "ANT", "DQ", "DQ", "BQ", "VGQ", "GHB", "VGQ"]})
```

How can I keep the rows of column `B` if it meets the condition of `exist for both EQ and CB`. For example, I would want to keep `ANT` because it exists for both `EQ` and `CB`, while `DQ` would be deleted. So the expected output for the `df` would be:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["EQ", "CB", "EQ", "CB"],
                       'B': ["ANT", "ANT", "VGQ", "VGQ"]})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution not using groupby() if you want code that may be easier to think about:

```
equities = df.B[df.A == 'EQ']
bonds = df.B[df.A == 'CB']
both = equities[equities.isin(bonds)]
```

That gives you:

```
0    ANT
5    VGQ
```

Which makes the last part easy:

```
df[df.B.isin(both)]
Out: 
    A    B
0  EQ  ANT
1  CB  ANT
5  EQ  VGQ
7  CB  VGQ
```

This is 3x faster on small data sets than groupby().filter().

Comment: kudos for figuring out what I am actually working with - equities and bonds :). will check it out!

Comment: @AK88: I tested using your small input sample and this is 3x faster than groupby().filter().  Can you test both using your real data and let us know the speeds?  If you use IPython, just put each solution into a function and run with `%timeit`.

Comment: testing it now. will get back to you shortly. I like the intuitive and simple steps of this method.

Comment: does having other columns affect this? I am not sure why I am seeing other stuff in the output other than EQ and CB ...

Comment: @AK88: Your original question made it sound like you wanted to see everything that had both EQ & CB, not that you also wanted to *not see* non-EQ, non-CB rows.  Just do `equities_and_bonds = df[df.A.isin(['EQ', 'CB'])]` as a first step and use that DataFrame for the remaining steps.  Or do the same filter at the end.  Other columns do not affect this.

Comment: Accepted! I just had a messy `B` column with punctuation. Had to clean them up.

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `filter`

```
s=df.groupby('B').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['EQ','CB']).isin(x['A']).all())
Out[7]: 
    A    B
0  EQ  ANT
1  CB  ANT
5  EQ  VGQ
7  CB  VGQ
```

Then

```
s=s[s.A.isin(['EQ','CB'])]
```

Comment: This filter supposed to get rid off other categories under `A`, right? I just ran this with my original dataset, but I failed to see `EQ` and `CB` only. The original dataset is much bigger, with duplicates of `EQ` and `CB`.

Comment: I feel like all the duplicates are getting smashed together. Plus I am seeing partial data. Investigating ...

Comment: Can having more than 2 columns be an issue? I am not sure why I keep seeing other categories along with `EQ` and `CB`.

Comment: @AK88 this solution is based on your sample data and expected output , you should check your original data with the sample and tell us the different , then make the question address your real data set problem

Comment: @AK88 also do not forget run `s=s[s.A.isin(['EQ','CB'])]` after groupby

Comment: It worked out! I had to clean commas and dots in `B`. Thanks! I am going to accept John's reply as I do not want to group items, but will upvote your other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Another way uses `transform` and slicing

```
m = df.groupby('B').A.transform(lambda x: (x.nunique() >= 2) 
                                        & (x.isin(['EQ', 'CB']).sum() >= 2))
df_final = df[m]

Out[623]:
    A    B
0  EQ  ANT
1  CB  ANT
5  EQ  VGQ
7  CB  VGQ
```

Comment: If have two same EQ per group ~

Comment: @YOBEN_S: yep, I thought of `nunique`. Your encouragement really pushes me to fix it :)